# Angle with horizontal when body escapes circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Q. A mass 'm' is released from a horizontal position in a vertical circle. The thread can withstand $T_{max} = mg$. Find angle of thread with horizontal when it breaks.

Seeing Farcher's comment, I got a big hint. Anyone interested in solution-

$$T-mg\cos\theta=ma (1)$$
$$T=m(a+g\cos\theta)$$
If $/theta = 90°$, the equation becomes-
$$T=m(a+g)$$

Thus, the string will break before reaching lowermost point.

By conservation of energy, we can write-
$$mgl=mgl(1-sin\theta)+[{1}/{2}]mv^2$$

Now from 1,
$$v=\sqrt{rg*(1-\sin\theta)}$$

$$mgl=[mgl(1-sin\theta)][1+{1}/{2}]$$
$$(1-sin\theta)({3}/{2})=1$$
$$\theta=sin^{-1}[1/3]$$

Note- to get v, I used the first equation and substituted mg for tension. Also, in the calculation of potential energy when thread breaks, I calculated height by- $$l-l[cos(90-\theta]=l(1-sin\theta).$$

Edit- I now realise; according to @freecharly and @Gert's answer, that taking h=0 at pt. of break-off also simplifies things.

Comment: At the lowest point the mass is undergoing centripetal acceleration.

Comment: The point I am making is at the bottom the tension is already in excess of $mg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Falling mass]

As the mass is released from stationary state, potential energy is converted to kinetic energy, $\Delta U=\Delta K$:
$$mgh=\frac12 mv^2$$
$$mgR\sin\theta=\frac12 mv^2\tag{1}$$
Where $R$ is the radius of the circle.

The velocity requires a centripetal force to be exerted by the thread:
$$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$
But to that has to be added the radial component of $mg$, to obtain the total tension $T$ in the thread:
$$T=F_c+mg\sin\theta$$
And from $(1)$:
$$mv^2=2mgR\sin\theta$$
$$F_c=\frac{2mgR\sin\theta}{R}=2mg\sin\theta$$
So that:
$$T=3mg\sin\theta$$
The breaking condition specifies:
$$T>mg$$
So that:
$$\large{\sin\theta>\frac13}$$

Comment: Well, this certainly feels a lot simpler than my solution. This was especially nice since you don't waste time in solving for velocity. Thanks!

Comment: Your centripetal force $F_C$ on the mass $m$ is directed towards the center of the rotation and the gravitational force on the mass is directed away from it. Why can you add the magnitudes of the two forces?

Comment: Because $T$ is a *reactive* force. It would be same if the mass was just dangling at the bottom: $mg$ points down but $T$ points up.

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational force component in thread direction is $$F_g=mg\cos{\theta}$$ ($\theta$ is angle to vertical.)In the rotational frame of the pendulum the centrifugal force is $$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{l}$$ The kinetic energy of the mass is equal to the loss in potential energy $$E_{kin}=\frac{mv^2}{2}=mgl\cos{\theta}$$ Thus the force $F$ on the string is $$F=F_g+F_c=mg\cos{\theta}+2mg\cos{\theta}=3mg\cos{\theta}$$ The string breaks when $F=T_{max}=mg$. Thus the string breaks at $$\cos{\theta}=\frac{1}{3}$$ $$\theta=\arccos{\frac{1}{3}}$$ The angle to the horizontal thus is $$\pi/2-\theta$$

Comment: Your answer is wrong, please see Gert's answer

Comment: Sorry, earlier you didn't specify what $\theta$ was. It is perfectly correct. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure of that. He doesn't say how the angle $\theta$ is defined.

Comment: @Akshat Batra - I chose the angle $theta$ to the *vertical* in my calculation.

Comment: I saw that in the last line where you mentioned 'angle to the horizontal'.